# The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out this error. although I use the Rocket Guide — part 3 section and although I change a bunch of coding and altered some code to fit my need. I'm getting this error in the id: gunpla.id
making it really hard to fix. I tried to find it and tried some other solutions that could fit but they do not work.  I would appreciate if someone could help me and show me the solution for this. this part is implementing the firestore from firebase.

```
Gunpla gunpla
package:gunpla_database/gunpla_details/gunpla_details_screen.dart

The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

```
import 'package:ant_icons/ant_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gunpla_database/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cupertino_icons/cupertino_icons.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class GunplaDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GunplaDetailsScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.gunpla,
  })  : assert(gunpla != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Gunpla gunpla;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(gunpla.name),
        actions: [
          StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
              stream: context.read<Backend>().favoritedGunplas,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final favoritedGunplas = snapshot.data;
                final isGunplaFavorited = favoritedGunplas.contains(gunpla.id);
                return IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<Backend>().setFavoritedGunpla(
                          id: gunpla.id,  <-- Error Is here
                          favorited: !isGunplaFavorited,
                        );
                  },
                  icon: isGunplaFavorited
                      ? const Icon(
                          AntIcons.heart,
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        )
                      : const Icon(AntIcons.heart_outline),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          if (gunpla.image.isNotEmpty) _ImageHeader(gunpla: gunpla),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              gunpla.name,
              style: textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              gunpla.series,
              style: textTheme.subtitle1,
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(AntIcons.column_width),
            title: Text('${gunpla.scale}'),
            subtitle: const Text('Available Scale'),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(AntIcons.colum_height),
            title: Text('${gunpla.grade}'),
            subtitle: const Text('Available Grade'),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.star_fill),
            title: Text('${gunpla.exclusive}'),
            subtitle: const Text('Exclusive'),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 56.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ImageHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ImageHeader({
    Key key,
    @required this.gunpla,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Gunpla gunpla;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 250,
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'hero-${gunpla.id}-image',
        child: Image.network(
          gunpla.image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the gunpla class with us.

Comment: tag: 'hero-${gunpla.id.toString()}-image',

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal i have the repo on [github](https://github.com/randycarrero/Gunpla_database/tree/fireabase)

Comment: Can you change `id: gunpla.id` to `id: '${gunpla.id}'` and see if it works?

Comment: @EdYuTo Thank you that made it finally work. my new question will this make the heart after favorite show no color? it picks up in firestore but does not change the color.

Comment: Make an update and describe what causes the problem and how you solved it...

Comment: @Nima The problem was that id: gunpla.id cant be assign and was interacting with other int to change it I had to change it to id: '${gunpla.id}' and it clear the error but it hides the after effect on the the results and does not refresh once it is favorited. it works in the backend but visually it does nothing. that's the temporary solution right now since it fixes the error but only creates a new problem.  i am rewriting the code since i have made changes to my master code and in hopes that it does not create this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Code shown is not enough, you might need to add the code for the Gunpla class.
However, you are most probably giving one of these text widgets an integer. Just add `.toString()` to the int inside the Text widget.

Comment: for some reason my app crashes now since i added this.

Comment: What is the error message? Can you also show the new code? It should be like this: `Text(gunpla.grade.toString())`

Comment: even after changing them to that text code for the grade, scale and exclusive. the id: gunpla.id is still in error, the error is at the on press. and if i remove the id: gunpla.id, it gets cleared. run the app great but cant save favorite.

Comment: Make sure the types of id on both ends match! You haven't uploaded the error message nor the code for the Gunpla class, but checking your github, the id in Gunpla is an int, whereas in the onpressed in github you wrote `.toString().`

Comment: the code for the gunpla class? I'm sorry but where can i find that. change i changed it on my visual studio code I will upload that. to GitHub. but right now there is no crash for the app it just comes blank the app in the simulator wont start.

Comment: [site I use to learn.](https://mdrobnych.medium.com/30-days-of-flutter-with-flutlab-code-party-9-1c4392811612) the 30 days of flutter challenge for rockets. that's what I used to learn and adjust to my needs.